# Reclassify values of the land use land cover class of Copernicus Global Land Cover Layers in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, raster-calculator, reclassify, land-classification, copernicus

I am using the Copernicus Global land cover layers:CGLS-LC100 collection 3 data set.
I want to reclassify the value of the lulc for my application.
Map is showing but when I want to reclassify the problem encounter is **lulc1.eq is not a function**.

```
// lulc
var lulc1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global")
.select('discrete_classification');
print(lulc1)
var properties = lulc1.propertyNames();
print('Metadata properties:', properties);
// print(lulc1.bandNames())

Map.addLayer(lulc1, {min: 0, max: 200, palette: ['#282828', '#FFBB22','#FFFF4C'
,'#F096FF','#FA0000','#B4B4B4','#F0F0F0','#0032C8','#0096A0','#FAE6A0',
'#58481F','#009900','#70663E','#00CC00','#4E751F','#007800','#666000','#8DB400'
,'#8D7400','#A0DC00','#929900   ','#648C00','#000080']}, "Land Cover")


print(data)
var lulcreclass = ee.Image(1).where(lulc1.eq(0).and(lulc1.eq(50)), 9)//**problem encounter in this lin**e
           .where(lulc.gt(50).and(lulc.lte(100)), 6)
           .where(lulc.gt(100).and(lulc.lte(150)), 4)
 Map.addLayer(lulcreclass,{},"LULC RECLASS")
```

Answer (score 5):

The variable **lulc1** is an image collection with 5 elements (images between years 2015 and 2019). If you want to reclassify it, it is preferable to map entire collection with a function. Following code fix up your issues and add your image collection to the Map View of GEE.

```
// lulc
var lulc1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global")
  .select('discrete_classification');

print(lulc1);

var properties = lulc1.propertyNames();
print('Metadata properties:', properties);
// print(lulc1.bandNames())

Map.addLayer(lulc1, {min: 0, 
                     max: 200, 
                     palette: ['#282828', '#FFBB22','#FFFF4C','#F096FF','#FA0000',
                     '#B4B4B4','#F0F0F0','#0032C8','#0096A0','#FAE6A0','#58481F',
                     '#009900','#70663E','#00CC00','#4E751F','#007800','#666000',
                     '#8DB400','#8D7400','#A0DC00','#929900','#648C00','#000080']}, 
                     "Land Cover");

var lulcreclass = lulc1.map(function (img) {
  
  return ee.Image(img)
    .where(img.eq(0).and(img.eq(50)), 9)
    .where(img.gt(50).and(img.lte(100)), 6)
    .where(img.gt(100).and(img.lte(150)), 4);
  
});

print(lulcreclass);

Map.addLayer(lulcreclass, {min: 0, 
                     max: 200, 
                     palette: ['#282828', '#FFBB22','#FFFF4C','#F096FF','#FA0000',
                     '#B4B4B4','#F0F0F0','#0032C8','#0096A0','#FAE6A0','#58481F',
                     '#009900','#70663E','#00CC00','#4E751F','#007800','#666000',
                     '#8DB400','#8D7400','#A0DC00','#929900','#648C00','#000080']},
                     "LULC RECLASS");
```

This can be observed in following picture with the same palette used in lulc1.

[image]